# midi controller for adobe premiere cs4

Tags: plugins, controller, midi, cs4, adobe-premiere

I'd like to develop a plugin for adobe premiere CS4 to controll its audio mixer control from my external midi device.

Although this seems to be a very popular subject, I could not find any tutorials, hints or whatsoever though I searched/googled for it desperately.

Just hoped that anyone of you guys has some experience and can give me some hints or at least some links to get started.

Greetings
Alex

---

So.. as it seems that I've been to cryptic with my question I'd like tu further explain it.

I already downloaded the Premiere Adobe CS4 SDK. That was clear to me as I want to automate Adobe Premiere, right? *g*

Next I saw that I can build plugins with Visual Studio and C++. However I don't really care about the programming language. Java, C#, C, C++, etc. are all ok for me.

I'd just like to know:

1. Is there a "best" language for this purpose (like some language that a midi "sdk" already exists for)
2. Is there already a tutorial/sample for connecting a midi controller with adobe premiere controls?
3. Might there even be an open source solution that I could enhance or configure?

Thank you for your answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you're going to want the [Premiere Pro SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/premiere.html).

Start with that and then come back and ask about opening a MIDI input in the language you end up using to build the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is not going to be very helpful to you. You can't make a plugin that does anything that is not in response to some user interface action, meaning the premiere's user interface. Some companies seem to get past that limitation because there are controllers made specifically for adobe premiere out there. My guess is they don't use the normal SDK.